# Silverlight - Width of a Textblock

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, width, textblock

It's a simple question:

How do I get the `Width` of a `TextBlock`?

The width of this `TextBlock` is set to Auto, in the XAML.

How do I get the `Width` of this `TextBlock` via code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the property

```
TextBlock.ActualWidth
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`ActualWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property